# Regex using condition on match results of another regex

Tags: regex, string, nested

I have a long string S and a string-to-string map M, where keys in M are the results of a regex match on S. I want to do a find-and-replace on S where, whenever one of the matches from that same regex is exactly one of my keys K in M, I replace it with its value M[K].

In order to do this I think I'd need to access the result of regex matches within a regex. If I try to store the result of a match and test equality outside a regex, I can't do my replace because I no longer know where the match was. How do I accomplish my goal?

Examples:

`S = "abcd_a", regex = "[a-z]", M = {a:b}`

result: "bbcd_b" because the regex would match the a's and replace them with b's

`S = "abcd_a", regex = "[a-z]*", M = {a:b}`

result: "abcd_b" because the regex would match "abcd" (but not replace it because it is not exactly "a") and the final 'a' (which it would replace because it is exactly "a")

Comment: Are you using any programming language or any editor ?

Comment: Some programming languages have that functionality built into their regex APIs, but not all.  If you're not using one of them, you'll have to write some code, like [ccf did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35810582/20938).  So, what exactly are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java. My editor is sublime, although Java will be doing the finding and replacing, not the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Thanks for AlanMoore's suggestion. The code is now simpler.

I tried using python (2.7x) to solve this simple example, but it can be achieved with any other language. What's important is the approach (algorithm). Hope it helps:

```
import re
from itertools import cycle

S = "abcd_a"
REGEX = "[a-z]"
M = {'a':'b'}

def ReplaceWithDict(pattern):
    # split by match group and map the match against map dict
    return ''.join([M[v] if v and v in M else v for v in re.split(pattern, S)])

print ReplaceWithDict('([a-z])')
print ReplaceWithDict('([a-z]*)')
```

Output:

```
bbcd_b
abcd_b
```

Comment: If you enclose the regex in a capturing group, you can skip the `findall()` step; everything you need will be in the `splits` list.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Updated. Thanks!